# Ruby removing diacritics from filenames - how to preserve them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, character-encoding

I have a directory full of files which have Unicode characters with diacritics in their file names, e.g. `ăn.mp3`, `bất.mp3`. (They're Vietnamese words.)

I'm iterating over these files using `Dir.glob("path/to/folder/*").each`, but the diacritics don't work properly. For example:

```
Dir.glob("path/to/folder/*").each do |file|
  # e.g. file = "path/to/folder/bất.mp3"
  word = file.split("/").last.split(".").first # bất
  puts word[1] # outputs "a", but should be "ấ"
end
```

Bizarrely, if I run `puts word` then the diacritics appear correctly, but if I `puts` individual letters, they're not there. The file names eventually get saved as an attribute in a table in my Rails app, and all kinds of problems are occurring from the diacritics being inconsistent and disappearing.

Clearly something's wrong with my encoding, but I have no idea how to go about fixing this. This is a problem not just with Rails but with Ruby itself, because the above output is from `irb`, independent of any Rails app.

(I'm running Ruby 2.0.0p247.)

What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to produce a diatric. One is to use the letter with the diatric on it. Another is to use the normal letter, and to immediately follow it with a special diatric letter. Are you sure you're not in the latter scenario? (If so, `puts 'a' + word[2]` should produce the letter wiht a diatric.)

Also, are you sure your strings are properly encoded using utf8 (or utf16), rather than sequences of bytes?

Comment: Ahhhh this is the problem. E.g.  `x[1] = "a", x[2] = "̂", x[3] = "́"`.

So my follow up question is: how do I convert the string from this form to the "single character diacritic" form? I need it in the latter form for a bunch of string manipulation that happens later in my app.

Comment: Also, everything appears to UTF-8, i.e. `"string".encoding` outputs `#<Encoding:UTF-8>`.

Comment: Wait... I figured out the answer to my own question. I wanted to use `UnicodeUtils`, specifically `UnicodeUtils.nfc(word)`.

Comment: Be wary that these are files, though because their name would actually be the version that includes those sequences of bytes, rather than the corresponding "printable" chars.

Comment: Good point. This doesn't seem to have caused any problems in my particular use case that I can see so far, but I'll bear this in mind, thanks.